# Comparing fractions and decimal approximations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rounding

I have the following Matlab function:

```
function in_out = in_or_out(x)
    sum = 0;
    for i = 1 : length(x)
        sum = sum + (x(i) - 1/2).^2;
    end 

    if sum <= 1/4
        in_out = 1;
    else
        in_out = 0;
    end
end
```

If I pass as input `[.8, .1]`, `sum = 0.250000000000000` after the for loop terminates. However, the `if sum <= 1/4` check fails and `0` is returned (i.e. according to Matlab `0.250000000000000` is not `<=` `1/4`). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tol = 0.000001
if ((sum<(1/4)) || (sum-(1/4))<tol)
    in_out = 1
else
    in_out = 0
end
```